# ul based html menu with css spilling into multiple lines

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists

So essentially I have a horizontal menu using ul and li elements styled with CSS which has a fixed height attribute for the ul but since the number of li elements are too many they are spilling over into multiple lines ...since the height of the ul is fixed, the li elements appear on the next line just fine but they are outside of the 'block' of the ul...so any further html content that appears starts showing inline with the li elments on the 2nd line?

I hope I have been able to describe the problem. I wish this was a publicly accessible site, for the CSS gurus to help with using firebug or web inspector.

Comment: The problem is clear, but what kind of a solution are you looking for?

Comment: Ideally, a solution where menu ul block element encloses all the li elements (not only on the 1st row), so even if the menu spills over into 2-3 rows (say the user has a small screen width) , the main  content is after this block, not inline with the li elements on the 2nd line...

Answer (score 2):

- use `min-height` on your UL, not `height`
- use `float:left` on your LIs
- use `display:block` on your A tags and put all other styling on the A tags. (DO NO STYLE THE LI TAGS OTHER THAN FLOAT:LEFT)

Comment: +1 for that last point (and one that's caught me out more times than I care to remember...) :)

Comment: Did that Diodeus, but no luck..here is the computed styles as shown by web inspector (safari):
UL: http://www.pastedump.com/paste/1271
LI: http://www.pastedump.com/paste/1272

Answer (score 0):

- you can expand the width of the
  container tag holding the ul, you do not have enough width for all the list elements
- if you can not enlarge the container try to cut down the width of the li's, using less padding and margin in between them.
- you can all so use a min-width property to bee sure that they will have enough space